# Check if a string contains palindromes separated by a hash symbol using a vector as an implementation of the stack

Tags: c++, vector, stack, cin, palindrome

I have to write a `bool mirrored()` function that has to return `true` if the input meets the following criteria.

> The string is mirrored if it contains palindrome substrings separated by one (and only one) hash symbol, and if all the palindromes are correct.

So it should return `true` for the following:

`#`, `####`, `abc#cba`, `##a#aabc#cba`

and `false` for the following:

`abc`, `abc#cv`, `abc#cbaa#aa`, `ab#bac##c`

This is my first exercise concerning the use of stack-related functions and I'm having difficulties with the following code:

```
bool isMirrored(){
    vector<char> stack;
    char s;
    bool hashSymbol = false;
    while(cin >> s){
        if(s=='#'){
            hashSymbol = true;
            while(hashSymbol && !stack.empty()){
                if(s==stack.back()){
                    stack.pop_back();
                }
                if(stack.empty()){
                    hashSymbol=false;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        stack.push_back(s);
    }
    return true;
}
```

My plan is when a `#` is not present, it loads the stack with characters and when a `#` is found, my algorithm goes into "check mode" (hence switching the `hashSymbol` variable to `true`) and checks if the topmost element of the stack is equal to the next character. If it is, then it checks for the next one and drops the topmost element of the stack. If the characters don't match, then the function returns `false`. When the stack is empty, then the algorithm should go into "input mode" again (`hashSymbol` switched to false) and the cycle begins anew. If the function didn't return false and the input is over, then it must return `true`.

My problem with this is that I can't figure out how to move to the next character in the input. When it finds a `#`, it enters the inner `while` statement while `s` is still the `#` character.

I thought of (at first glance at least) another possible much simpler solution, but I still can't figure out how to move to the next character in the input when a `#` is found.

```
vector<char> stack;
char s;
while(cin >> s){
    if(s!='#'){
        stack.push_back(s);
    }
    else{
        if(!stack.empty()){
            [this is where I would check for equal characters]
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}

return stack.empty();
```

Comment: Still wrapping my head around how `##a#aabc#cba` is supposed to line up as  *passing* the myriad of conditions you stated, specifically how it passes the "contains palindrome substrings separated by one (and only one) hash symbol,", when clearly aabc is *not* such a beast.

Comment: This is where a proper debugger would really come in handy.

Comment: @WhozCraig #|#|a#a|abc#cba two empty, one single char

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe it must be the late hour, because I have no idea how you got that. This 'thing' per the description is supposed to *validate* the input string; not contrive a derivative from said-same, or so I foolishly thought "if the input meets the following criteria." was intended to mean.

Comment: @WhozCraig These kind of assignments often have problems with a precise/understandable formulation.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I get that. Seen that enough times. And I *thought* the specific stated objective in the first two sentences of the OPs post was both precise *and* understandable. There I go thinking again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hints for the first version.

The

```
while(hashSymbol && !stack.empty()){
```

Is superfluous. Check just one character at a time.

```
stack.push_back(s);
```

pushes the '#' on the stack too.

I think you will have an easier time to adapt your second version rather than correcting the first.

Your not far away from a solution..

Comment: And if I find a `#` how can I move to the next character on `cin`?

Comment: @CoderStudent8822 The `while(cin >> s){` takes care of that.  Just don't push the # on the stack.